# celery is running but it is not executing any task

Tags: redis, celery, fastapi, celery-task

The Celery with Redis is Running but the task is not executing in FastAPI

command - **redis-server** -

[image: redis-server]

command - **celery -A core.celery_app_work worker --loglevel=info -P eventlet** -

[image: celery -A core.celery_app_work worker --loglevel=info -P eventlet]

**celery flower output**

[image: celery flower output]

I want to execute my task in fastapi using celery

celery_app_work.py

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

celery_app = Celery(__name__, 
                    broker='redis://localhost:6379', 
                    backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')

celery_app.conf.task_routes = {'backend.core.worker_task.*':'example-queue'}
```

worker_task.py

```
from .celery_app_work import celery_app

data = {'task':'celery'}

@celery_app.task(name="create_task")
def test_celery(data: str):
    print('inside celery')
    for i in range(10):
        return data
```

```
structure - 

|--backend
     | 
     |--core
     |    |---celery_app_work.py
     |    |---worker_task.py
     |
     | ---main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing), the format should be  app.conf.task_queues

```
celery_app.conf.task_routes = {'backend.core.worker_task.*': {'queue': 'example-queue'}}
```

Additionally, you probably need to specify to Celery that the queue `example-queue` should exist:

```py
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

exchange = Exchange('default', type='direct')

app.conf.task_queues = (
    Queue('example-queue', exchange, routing_key='default'),
)
```

Comment: i think the problem is celery is unable to find the task it is dificult to specify the module path. you can see my second screen shot there the task will be empty.

Comment: Yeah, there could be an issue there too. If you are running your commands from the `backend` directory, you should probably just specify the module as `core.worker_task`. You can also try checking if it picks up the task if you remove the `task_routes` config completely.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working, so i imported the task directly but now it is causing circualr import error but now the celery can fetch task